# Jump to comment in preview when clicking on in-text comment "square"

Tags: macos, preview

When I'm in the "highlights and notes" view in Preview, I can click on a comment in the grey area, and it will jump to the comment/highlight.

**Is there anyway to do the opposite, where I can click on the highlight or "comment square" within the text, to jump to the sidebar note itself?**

**Moreover, if I am not in "highlights and notes" view, is there a way to click on the in-text highlight/square and have the comment appear if it exists?**

I do not want to have to right-click and hit "edit note" to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes... you just click it.

Apparently it just wasn't working for me (bug) until I tried to add a new note, and then deleted that note. Now I can simply click a comment square with left click to show the comment.